# Print row and check if that row is inside a csv

Tags: python, csv

I've a script that uses the data I have in the clipboard (rows with text) to check if it exist in a web site with the help of Selenium. If that records can't be found, prints the information of the row (in order to tell me what was NOT found).

What I am trying to achieve now is for the rows which are not found in the web browser to check also if it exist in a CSV I've in my laptop. So the final result should be: print (row) + Is in the CSV or Is not in CSV.

I created the below script but it isn't working as expected. What I added from original one to the new script is mentioned with the ###.

Can you give me some tips to put it working correctly. Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import csv
import tkinter as tk

path_to_Ie = 'C:\\Python34\\ChromeDriver\\ChromeDriver.exe' # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_Ie)
url = 'https://wwww.test.corp/'
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']").send_keys("xxxx")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']").send_keys("xxxx")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-link']").click()

browser.get('https://test.com/troubleshoot#displayall=true')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/label").click()

root = tk.Tk()
# keep the window from showing
root.withdraw()
# read the clipboard

today = (time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y"))
file = 'Z:\\deleted_%s.csv' % today

rows = root.clipboard_get().split('\n')
rows = [row.strip() for row in rows]

validation = ""
while validation != "Select All (1)":

   for row in rows:
        browser.get('https://test.com/troubleshoot#displayall=true')
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(row)
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        validation = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").text
        if validation != "Select All (1)": # or anything that is a falsy validation
           browser.get('https://test.com/troubleshoot#displayall=true')
           time.sleep(1)
           browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/label").click()
           time.sleep(1)
           print(row) ###### below is what I added from the original##########
           with open(file, 'rt') as f:
              reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
              for row in reader:
               for field in row:
                 if field == row:
                  print ("%s exist in the CSV") % row
           continue  ###### above is what I added from the original##########
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click()
   else:
      break
```

Comment: HOW exactly is it not working? One mistake I see is you need to use `print ("%s exist in the CSV") % row` to have the `row` printed — the `s` after the `%` character is missing in your code.

Comment: Ups, already fixed. The problem is that seems these new lines added are not changing anything.. code works as before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely because you've got two variables named `row` being used at the same time. One defined is by the outer `for row in rows:` statement and there's another one being created by in the inner `for row in reader:` statement.

To fix it, rename the inner one something else, like `for csvrow in reader:`, and change all references to it accordingly.

Comment: Just one last question, what if I had 2 csv to check instead of 1. There is a simple way to do it? Instead of repeat the lines : with open... . Thanks a lot

Comment: There's a couple ways I can think of to optimize checking against two (or more) csv files at once, but not significantly.Your current implementation is rather slow even for checking against one because it reads and processes every field in every row of the whole file for each row from the clipboard. Since the file probably doesn't change while doing this, I would cache the necessary information from the csv file in memory, which would speed things up dramatically. After doing that, adding another csv to check against the same way — using cached info — would likely be a non-issue.